# Script task make a lock in the text file while checking the last modified date

Tags: vbscript, ssis

We have two servers say ServerA and ServerB. In ServerA a package will load the text file from the FTP which is pushed by the other package in ServerB. These both the packages running in almost same time.

The package in ServerA will check for last modified date of the source file in FTP before loading it. If the last modified date is same as the current date it will load the file. If the date is not same it will wait for 10 seconds and check the last modified date and compare it to the current date. This will keep occurring until the latest file pushed into the FTP path by server B. I have done this through a Script task.

The problem is, In case the script task in server A started already (Started checking the last modified date for every 10 seconds) and the package in ServerB trying to export data to the same file, it will throw a error says `"The file is used by the another process"`. How can i fix this issue? Please advice me..

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deal with this issue, e.g.:

- Enable error-handling (`On Error Resume Next`) in the import script and skip the import, or loop until the other process has finished writing to the file. Note that error-handling is dangerous, because it will effectively suppress all error messages that aren't explicitly handled. Only enable this locally and disable it as soon as it's not needed anymore (`On Error Goto 0`).
- Have the export script create a lock file, which is removed after the export is complete, and have the import script check for the absence of that lock file before trying to import the data file.
- Have the export script export the data to a temporary file and rename that temp file after the export is complete.

Comment: Seems like, my question bit confused you. Actually export task didn't create the lock. The lock is created by the script task. Script task will only check for last update date( hold until the the new file pushed to production). Due to the lock created by the script task, the export task getting failed.

Comment: It's a legacy system. My senior developers didn't add any date values to the file name. When I ask them, is that ok If I added a logic to add a date string to the file name, so that I don't need to check the file last modified date and shall just look for a file with the expected name. But my senior don' wants to do that and I don't want to argue with him.

Comment: In which intervals will the export process write to the file? If the exporter writes every `n` minutes, and the import needs `x` minutes to retrieve the file (with `n < x`), you could run the importer if the last modified date is no more than `n - x` minutes ago.